# Can I boost the Wifi Direct signal from my TV with a router?

Tags: router

So I have a Sony KDL-60W610B tv and a Windstream Sagemcom Wireless xDSL Bonding router Model: F@ST 4320 router and I would like to use that router to amplify the build in wifi from the TV. I like using WiFi direct but the connection is so bad I have to be right next to the tv. Is there a way to connect the router to the tvs build in WiFi and basically use the router as a connector to boost the strength?

Answer (score 0):

You may be overlooking an important point.  Wi-fi Direct is [designed to work without a router](http://www.howtogeek.com/178691/htg-explains-what-is-wi-fi-direct-and-how-does-it-work/).  You just have a problematic device, or maybe the manufacturer's design spec just did not intend for its Wi-Fi Direct to be used at great distances.

Comment: Still. Do you know how to do it?